# Unexpected results using order() on data frame

Tags: r

This is my first time asking a question here, so please be patient.

I'm having an issue with using `order()`

This is the [data frame](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bze8JK0YhMfacEFGbVRqcklzaDQ/edit?usp=sharing). It has 294 observations and 46 variables.

This is the code that I'm using

```
i <- order(data[ , 17], data[ , 2], decreasing = FALSE)

rdata <-data[i, ]
```

For ease of reading, I've removed all of the variables except the two that I am ordering by. Here are the [results](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bze8JK0YhMfaZFZWNVZnNE93Tlk/edit?usp=sharing).

What I wanted was for column 17 to be ordered from smallest to largest, and if two or more values in column 17 were the same, for those to be ordered alphabetically by column 2.

For some reason, the results aren't quite correct. Perhaps, I have too many observations or something, but instead of everything being ordered by `column 17 (1:294)` it's ordered by `column 17 (251:294, 1:250)`

**Sorry, how else can I share the data?**

Basically, rows `251 to 294` should be "prepended" to the beginning of the result data frame

**Thank you for your help**

```
i <- order(as.numeric(data[ , 17]), data[ , 2], decreasing = FALSE)

rdata <-data[i, ]
```

**This works properly now.**

Comment: Please don't share data via google drive. It asks people to log-in. I won't do that simply to see your data.

Comment: See [this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on how to share data. Also doesn't `rdata<-data[order(data[,17],data[,2]),]` work?

Comment: You're using `order` incorrectly. Try `?order` to learn more.

Comment: Yes, what you posted works, but I get the same results.

Comment: what's the class of `df[,2]` (check `class(df[,2])`)? In case it's `factor` you could try `rdata<-data[order(data[,17],as.character(data[,2])),]`. Does that change anything in the resulting data.frame?

Comment: Start with a nice small test matrix so you can see what's happening. Then fix your code.

Answer (score 0):

If i get you right, Here is what you should be doing -

```
i     <- data [order(data [,17],data [,2]),]
rdata <- subset(i, select=c(i[,17],i[,2]))
```

Or you can use the plyr package and say -

```
i     <- arrange(data,data[,17],data[,2])
rdata <- subset(i, select=c(i[,17],i[,2]))
```